# plotting average % vs % rank (Average score at average performance)

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Imagine there are 3 grades. Physics, Maths, Chemistry.
Total grade is (Physics + Maths + Chemistry / 3)

On the x-axis I plot the total grade in terms of %. So best student is at 1.00, worst student is at 0.00 and median student at 0.50.

On the y-axis, I want to plot what % makeup each class had to their total grade.

So as to see if there is any change depending on how good/bad a student did and which classes different levels of students excel at.

Here is a copy of my current data frame.

```
Observations: 269,049
Variables: 3
$ TotalRank <dbl> 0.00, 0.30, 0.30, 0.29, 0.21, 0.68, 0.22, 0.02, 0.13, 0.44, 0.02, 0.37, 0.42, 0.40, 0.43, 0.55, 0...
$ Class    <chr> "Chemistry", "Maths", "Maths", "Physics", "Maths", "Maths", "Physics", "Maths", "Chemistry"...
$ Value    <dbl> 0.34, 0.36, 0.36, 0.43, 0.41, 0.38, 0.41, 0.39, 0.34, 0.35, 0.35, 0.34, 0.34, 0.39, 0.33, 0.35, 0...
```

My goal is to have a graph that looks like this:

[image]

My code:

```
ggplot(DATAFRAME, aes(x = TotalRank, y = Value, fill = Class)) + 
  geom_area()
```

The x-axis seems to work fine, but in the y-axis it just adds up the points for each x value, rather than plotting the average value at that point.

How do I plot the average y value at each x point, divided into let's say 100 bins.

EDIT: This is what my plot looks like, please ignore values as they are an example.

[image]

This is how I built the dataframe.

```
dataframe <- dataframe %>%
    mutate(ChemistryPc = round(Chemistry/TotalGrade, 2),
        MathsPc = round(Maths/TotalGrade, 2),
        PhysicsPc = round(Physics/TotalGrade, 2),
        TotalRank = round(percent_rank(TotalGrade), 2))


dataframe <- dataframe %>%
  gather(key = 'Class', value = 'Value', -TotalRank)
```

Here are values:

```
        Chemistry    Maths        Physics  TotalGrade 
1        47.63       20.41          70.31  138.35
2       142.88       95.25         163.29  401.42
3       142.88       95.25         163.29  401.42
4       170.10       77.11         145.15  392.36
5       138.35       65.77         136.08  340.20
6       229.06      161.03         210.92  601.01
7       142.88       68.04         136.08  347.00
8        86.18       52.16          83.91  222.25
9       102.06       77.11         120.20  299.37
10      174.63      122.47         195.04  492.14
11       74.84       47.63          92.99  215.46
12      154.22      115.67         183.70  453.59
13      163.29      111.13         204.12  478.54
14      181.44       99.79         188.24  469.47
15      161.03      127.01         197.31  485.35
16      190.51      120.20         231.33  542.04
17      165.56      124.74         201.85  492.15
18      254.01      131.54         219.99  605.54
19      258.55      174.63         240.40  673.58
20      233.60      154.22         247.21  635.03
```

Comment: You aren't able to plot an average because you haven't calculated one. What sort of code have you written so far to prep your data? Otherwise, you're asking 1. how do you calculate averages at some sort of binned points, and 2. how do you then plot those values.

Comment: I don't know how to calculate the average based on the total rank number. I've done a LOT of data cleaning/prepping so far, I created all the ranks/values. The original data was just values, I put them into % form.

Comment: I will post now what data prep I did

Comment: Okay, I think you might want to split this into two separately posted questions, one on how to calculate the averages, and one on how to build this type of plot

Comment: All right, I think people will be pretty upset with how I post it as I am not sure how to word what I am doing. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: try to post an usable example, using `dput` for example, or `head`, or `print`. To calculate your average you can try to use the `rollmean` function of `zoo` library, averaging over a number of point that is the length of your data divided per 100. You then plot the result. I ll post an answer if you give usable data

Comment: added values for you, is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I used :

```
dataframe %>%
  select(Sex, ChemistryPc, MathsPc, PhysicsPc, TotalRank) %>%
  group_by(TotalRank) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(-Sex), funs(mean(., na.rm=TRUE))) %>%
  gather(key = 'Class', value = 'ValuePc', -TotalRank)
```

then used

```
ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = TotalRank, y = ValuePc, fill = Class)) + 
  geom_area()
```

and got my plot.

[image]